How to stop the Go `plugin` package from fighting with `go test -coverprofile`?
I have a Go app where to use it, and therefore to test it, I need to build a .so file. The tests work fine if I just do go test ./..., but if I add the -coverprofile flag, e.g. go test ./... -coverprofile=coverage.out then building the .so file fails with plugin.Open("<filepath to plugin>"): plugin was built with a different version of <package>. Note that the package in question is one of my own packages, part of the app which the .so file needs to import in order to interact with it.
I was expecting it to "just work" as it does when I do go test without -coverprofile. The only thing I can say I've "tried" is googling hard for clues and asking this same question in three other places, in all of which I drew a blank. There is nothing obvious to try. I'm baffled.
